# Linear regression with Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) update rule

Tags: python, linear-regression

I understand that in SGD we update the weights w.r.t. to a single training example such as:

```
for i in range(m):
   weights = weights + (alpha * gradient) # for each i in m
```

Do we then calculate the new mean squared error (my cost function) based on this single update or after an entire run through the training set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a single update.  The gradient is estimated using a single training example, and this is then used to update your weights.  After the update, you can then compute the new loss function to see how your optimization is doing.

Comment: So it is:

For each d in training set:
1. Update weight wrt to d
2. Compute new error

Comment: Sounds correct :) You can then run through the training set as many times as necessary.  Note that you might have to shuffle the training set to avoid the error signal oscillating.

Comment: Do you compute the loss function w.r.t to that single data point or w.r.t. the entire training set?

Comment: If you think about what you are trying to achieve, you'll realize that computing the loss w.r.t. a single point does not make any sense :)